# jQuery live method: can't stop event from bubbling the DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure, but it seems like a bug.

Here are samples:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNrZu/

Maybe i'm doing something wrong?
Any solution for this?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)?

> Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events.

[`.live()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binds the event handlers to the document root. You can even see this in the order of the logs you get:

```
this should't be triggered
clicked
```

The event handler at the `div` is executed *before* the live handler for the `a` element.

If you *have to* use `.live()`, then the only way to solve this would be to also bind the event the event handler to the `div` with `.live()`:

```
$('div').live('click', function(){
    console.log("this should't be triggered");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QNrZu/6/)

If you don't have to use `.live()`, then just bind the handler to the `a` element in the normal way, using [`.click()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`.bind()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: Thanks didn't noticed that notice over there. Guess i'll have to create custom function then. To avoid re-binding in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

use `bind` instead of `live`, live has to cater for the dynamically added elements so event bubbling cannot be stopped

```
   $('div').click(function(){
        alert('will not be triggered');
    });

    $('a').bind('click',function(e){
        console.log('clicked');   
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("first");
        alert("second");    
    });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QNrZu/3/